# Tkinter, can I clear all entries after inputting wrongly and press 'Submit' button by user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When the user has **incorrect input** and press'**Submit**' button. The **invalid message box** will be shown. After the invalid message box has **closed** by the user, I want the entries by the user can be **cleared**.

I have searched for some information. Someone recommends using '**delete**'. However, I **get some error** when I use 'delete'

Someone recommends setting the entry variable again as ''. However, I am confused **where should I reset the variable**.

Can anyone tell me how to do ?

```
def user_login(window):
    # some codes to find whether valid or not. Valid: found = True
    entry_value = entry_value.get()
    if found:
        messagebox.showinfo(title='Successful login',
                            message='Valid password. Welcome to 7vinBB air traffic control system !')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Error',
                             message='Invalid password. Please enter again. You have  ' + str(5-count1) + ' times left')

class LoginFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
         super().__init__(master)
         self.entry_value = entry(self,
                                  font='Courier 17')
         self.login_button = button(command=lambda: user_login(root))

         self.entry_value.place(x=330, y=245)      
         self.login_button.place(x=440, y=420)

 root = Tk()
 lf = LoginFrame(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't provide the code.

Comment: There are my brief codes. How should I  modify?

Comment: Consider adding code provided by BeastCoder below in the answer in your `else` block, should work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using delete is a good selection

Use it like this:

```
<entry widget>.delete(0, 'end')
```

> The 0 specifies the first place (index 0), and 'end' represents that last place (the end)

In Your Case It Would Be:

```
entry_value.delete(0, 'end')
```

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

```
username.delete(0, END)

password.delete(0,END)

username=tk.Entry(root)
username.grid(row=0,col=1)  

password=tk.Entry(root)
password.grid(row=1,col=1)
```

username and password is the name of the field(or)entry that is used to enter values in it.